# Install ruby-opengl 0.60.1 on Ubuntu? ...in order to add 'gl', 'glu', and 'glut' extensions

Tags: opengl, rubygems, glut, glu, libgosu

How does one install ruby-opengl-0.60.1 on Ubuntu?

I keep trying

```
$ gem install ruby-opengl --version 0.60.1
```

and I am running into the following error:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
ERROR: 'rake/gempackagetask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 
'rubygems/package_task' instead.
/home/matias/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@sampleGemset/gems/ruby-opengl-0.60.1/
Rakefile:24:in `<top (required)>'
```

Perhaps I could manually change the "package task" parameter in the Rakefile
and then attempt a local gem install?...

I have found the following urls where the package can be downloaded for manual installation:

```
rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=2103

launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ruby-opengl/0.60.1+dfsg1-2
```

And the following appears to be a patch or a small modification:

```
gist.github.com/tociyuki/2479308
```

I tried downloading the gem from the launchpad url, and then I tried
    $ gem install ruby-opengl-0.60.1.gem
from the Downloads folder, and it gave me a ton of errors.

I eventually tried:
    $ sudo apt-get install libopengl-ruby

which seemed to work, and now when I do:
    $ gem list -r ruby-opengl
I get:

```
\*** REMOTE GEMS \***
ruby-opengl (0.61.0, 0.60.0 i386-mswin32)
ruby-opengl2 (0.60.6)
```

I believe that i386-mswin32 is version 0.60.1 for windows.

With this configuration, I try running Sapphire.rb and it still doesn't work.

I already have ruby-opengl versions 0.60.0 and 0.61.0 installed, but I need 0.60.1 because it creates the 'gl', 'glu', and 'glut' extensions which are required in order to run some .rb files which I have copied from other people. These .rb files are video games created with the [Gosu gem](http://github.com/jlnr/gosu).

This is for use specifically with the Gosu gem. Even more specifically, I am trying to run the Sapphire game (github.com/KoBeWi/Sapphire), which also requires the [Texplay gem](http://github.com/banister/texplay).

Or is there another way to activate the 'gl', 'glu', and 'glut' extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the nice people at libgosu for providing the answer:

```
$ gem install opengl --pre
```

took care of everything! Now if someone else runs into this
same difficulty, the answer is here!